# Concatenation of several Strings to use for encryption

Tags: java, encryption, biginteger

I have an encryption method which converts several Strings each to byte[] and appends them to an array to perform later an encryption.

Now I have to use an other method which receives only one String to perform the same encryption.

I get the same cipher when I use the first method with a list of Strings, and the second one with a single String compound on the concatenation of all the Strings of the list of the first method EXCEPT when one of these Strings is a representation like, for example:

```
String str = 
"2CD03B874A418A7C90E1A32F6CB5B952BB29B734A397851903AA403BD9ADDD9CD19AF583A067D9812B8B68EE1884FB347C030609CE31ECF4"
```

I've tried to convert the sign of the Strings (in case there is one) like this:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(str, 16);
if (bi.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) {
    bi = bi.abs().not().add(BigInteger.ONE);
}                   
String str2 = new String(bi.toByteArray(), "windows-1252");
```

Any hints?

EDITED:
First method:

```
String crypt1(ArrayList<String[]> list) {
   for(String str:list) {
      update(str, str.length());
   }
   byte[] out = new byte[16];
   convert(out);
   return getHex(out);
}

void update(byte[] buf, int len) {
   ...
   System.arraycopy(buf, 0, mainBuffer, index1, len); 
   ...
}

String convert1(byte[] out) {
    ... // performs MD5 conversion over "out"
}

String getHex(byte[] bytes) {
    String hex = "";
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        hex += Integer.toHexString(0xFF & b);
    }
    return hex;
}
```

Second method:

```
String crypt2(ArrayList<String[]> list) {
   String text = "";
   for(String str:list) {
      text += str;
   }
   return convert2(text);
}

String convert2(String text) {
    ... // gets text bytes
    ... // performs MD5 conversion
    return cipher;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'Strings is a representation like' ?
it's the most bad practice solution, but you can split the example String to a few sub strings and then feed it to the first function

Comment: Unfortunately did not work like this, even for those kind of Strings where appending had worked: if I split it into 2 Strings, I obtain a cipher, and if into 4 Strings, an other one (and so on), and these do not ever match whith the correct one given by the first function...

Comment: can you provide with the smallest code snippet of the 2 functions so we can see what differ one function from the other

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to disclose these functions, but please see my update to the description, this might help a bit to clarify it...

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of moving parts and code duplication
I suggest to use only 2 different methods:

- get string and return byte[]
- get array of strings and return byte[] of the concatenated string

and use the **exact logic** once you have a byte[] object, get rid of `convert2()` and also `update()` 
a lot of functions makes the code more prone to errors and bugs

this way you can check if the string/s entered to those function returned the same byte[]

example of draft code can be like so

```
public byte[] stringToByte(String str) {
    return str.getBytes();
}

public byte[] StringArrayToByte(ArrayList<String> list){
    String newStr = "";
    for (String str : list)
            newStr += str;

    return newStr.getBytes();
}
```

also I suggest you take a look at apache lib, they implemented most of the string manipulation and crypto functions 
https://commons.apache.org/

Comment: Thanks Shahaf; the problem keeps being, that appending all String elements of the list in a single String did not produce the "correct" cipher result in the case of the sample string of my header. I found out that this is a BigInteger representated as a String, therefore in Function1 they convert "normal" strings using "byte[] b = str1.getBytes(charset);", but for those BigIntegeres given as String they use "byte[] b = new BigInteger(str2, 16).toByteArray();"

Comment: If I append the str2 to the other strings to have a single String to be used for Function2, I don't get the correct cipher. If I convert this str2 to BigInteger then to byte and then to String, and I append it to the other ones for Function2, id doesn't work either... I suspect that I'm not handling correctly a sign or something else with this sample string, because when I do what exposed some lines above with some other BigIntegeres representated also like Strings, then IT WORKS, arghhhh! Some of then may have sign, others not? I need to manage handling any String-representation...